# Get ClaimsPrincipal for non-default authentication scheme

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, cookies

When having multiple authentication schemes, how do I access the ClaimsPrincipal for **non-default** ClaimsPrincipal?

I have a POC app that has 2 authentication schemes, both are cookie-based. When I login with the first (default) authentication scheme, I can see the created identity and associated claims on `context.User`.

However, when I try to login with the second (non-default) authentication scheme, I do not get any identities or claims at all even though the second cookie is set.

What am I missing here?

```cs
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

const string scheme1 = "cookie1";
const string scheme2 = "cookie2";

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(scheme1)
    .AddCookie(scheme1, (options) => { options.Cookie.Name = scheme1; })
    .AddCookie(scheme2, (options) => { options.Cookie.Name = scheme2; });

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.User, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
        WriteIndented = true
    });

    return result;
});

app.MapGet("/login1", async context =>
{
    await SignInAsync(context, "Name1", scheme1);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});

app.MapGet("/login2", async context =>
{
    await SignInAsync(context, "Name2", scheme2);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});

app.MapGet("/logout1", async context =>
{
    await context.SignOutAsync(scheme1);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});
app.MapGet("/logout2", async context =>
{
    await context.SignOutAsync(scheme2);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});

app.UseAuthentication();

app.Run();

return;

async Task SignInAsync(HttpContext context, string name, string authScheme)
{
    var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, ClaimValueTypes.String, "CIA");
    var claims = new List<Claim> {claim};
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authScheme);
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await context.SignInAsync(authScheme, user);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create authorization policy, and also add authorization to your "/" mapping, another way it will be fetching user from default scheme only.

**Steps -**

1. Add Authorization middleware and set policy -

```
AuthorizationPolicy multiSchemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(scheme1, scheme2)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = multiSchemePolicy;
});
```

2. Use Authorization middleware right after Authentication middleware -

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

3. Add RequireAuthorization() to "/" mapping -

```
app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.User, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
        WriteIndented = true
    });

    return result;
}).RequireAuthorization();
```

**Full class will be looking like this -**

```
// Add services to the container.

using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

const string scheme1 = "cookie1";
const string scheme2 = "cookie2";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(scheme1, (options) => { 
        options.Cookie.Name = scheme1;
    })
    .AddCookie(scheme2, (options) =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = scheme2;
    });

AuthorizationPolicy multiSchemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(scheme1, scheme2)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = multiSchemePolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/login1", async context =>
{
    await SignInAsync(context, "Name1", scheme1);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});

app.MapGet("/login2", async context =>
{
    await SignInAsync(context, "Name2", scheme2);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});

app.MapGet("/logout1", async context =>
{
    await context.SignOutAsync(scheme1);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});
app.MapGet("/logout2", async context =>
{
    await context.SignOutAsync(scheme2);
    context.Response.Redirect("/");
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.User, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
        WriteIndented = true
    });

    return result;
}).RequireAuthorization();

app.Run();

async Task SignInAsync(HttpContext context, string name, string authScheme)
{
    var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, ClaimValueTypes.String, "CIA");
    var claims = new List<Claim> {claim};
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authScheme);
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await context.SignInAsync(authScheme, user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So without an explicit policy, the authorization process only populates the User object with the default authentication scheme, brilliant!